# Validating inputs with same name[ ] and class of different rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have 3 inputs on a div (repeated several times), I want to validate that if the user enters a value on coreid it's necessary to insert the amount, and to have a value on fullname(it is given with the id from sql automatically, if it doesn'thave a value..the id is incorrect) this on the same row, as they have all the same class and names, it makes the validation but it doesn't matter if they're at the same row or not.. it makes the submit even if I insert a coreid at the 1st row, the fullname on the 3rd row and the amount at the 2nd row.
Any help, please?

```js
$("#myform").submit(function() {
  var currentForm = this;

  var allinputs = 0;
  var coreid = 0;
  var fullname = 0;
  var amount = 0;
  //if all inputs are empty
  $(this).find('input.cardField').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") allinputs += 1;
  });
  if (allinputs) {
    //checks if coreid has a value
    $(this).find('input.cardField.id').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") coreid += 1;
    });
    //checks if fullname has a value
    $(this).find('input.cardField.name').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") fullname += 1;
    });
    //checks if amount has a value
    $(this).find('input.cardField.cardAmount').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") amount += 1;
    });

    //if user inserts an id it must have a value on name
    if (coreid) {
      var empty = $(this).parent().find("input.cardField.name").filter(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") fullname += 1;
      });
      if (fullname) {
        //the name is given when the user inserts the id
        alert("it has a name, the id is correct");
      } else {
        bootbox.alert('Please insert a valid id');
        return false;
      }
      //the user inserts an amount but not an id
    } else {
      bootbox.alert('Please insert an employee id');
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    //the user can continue if he confirms
    bootbox.confirm("Empty fields, Do you want to continue?",
      function(result) {
        if (result) {
          currentForm.submit();
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
```

If a user inserts one of the three inputs it is mandatory that he inserts the 3 values...
No matter if the other rows (other divs) are empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over the DIVs. In each DIV, get the value of the `id` field. If it's not empty, check the other two fields.

```js
$("#myform").submit(function() {
  var currentForm = this;

  var allinputs = 0;
  var missinginputs = false;
  //if all inputs are empty
  $(this).find('input.cardField').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") allinputs += 1;
  });
  if (allinputs) {
    //checks if coreid has a value
    $(this).find('div').each(function(index) {
      var coreid = $(this).find("input.cardField.id").val();
      var fullname = $(this).find("input.cardField.name").val();
      var amount = $(this).find("input.cardField.amount").val();
      if (coreid == "" && fullname == "" && amount == "") {
        // all inputs in row are empty, skip it
        return;
      } else if (coreid == "" || fullname == "" || amount == "") {
        bootbox.alert(`Enter all fields in row #${index}`);
        missinginputs = true;
      }
    });
    return !missinginputs;
  } else {
    //the user can continue if he confirms
    bootbox.confirm("Empty fields, Do you want to continue?",
      function(result) {
        if (result) {
          currentForm.submit();
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" name="coreid[]" class="form-control cardField id">
  <input type="text" name="fullName[]" class="form-control cardField name">
  <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control cardField amount">
</div>
</form>
```